# Como criar uma coluna no R sob condições específicas?

Tags: r, data.frame

Considere o seguinte data.frame:

```
data <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","d"), y=c(2,2,1,2),w=c(4,4,2,2),z=c(25,16,24,30), k=c("sim","nao","sim","nao"))
```

Como incluir uma nova coluna onde teremos valor 1 para as linhas com y=2, w=4 e z<25 & z>15, e valor 0 para quaisquer outras características?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta fazer uma condição lógica composta das várias condições elementares da pergunta.

```
data$novaCol <-  with(data, as.integer(y == 2 & w == 4 & 15 < z & z < 25))
```

Como os valores lógicos `FALSE/TRUE` em `R`são codificados como `0/1`, usamos a função `as.integer` para mudarem de classe. Outras duas maneiras seriam somar `0L` (zero inteiro) ou multiplicar por `1L` (um inteiro). Mas estas duas maneiras apesar de serem muito usadas são pouco legíveis e na verdade são "hacks". Forçam o `R`a tratar os valores lógicos como números inteiros de modo a poder efetuar as operações aritméticas.

```
with(data, (y == 2 & w == 4 & 15 < z & z < 25) + 0L)
with(data, (y == 2 & w == 4 & 15 < z & z < 25) * 1L)
```