# R: Criação de uma nova variável usando if e else

Tags: r, variáveis, if

Estou com uma base de 9 milhões de linhas. Estou tentando fazer uma nova variável chamada `base$trs_localidade` utilizando a  variável `base$iso_pais` sendo:

```
base$iso_pais<- c( '076', '840', '076','442' , '052' , '076')

if(x = '076'){
  print('NACIONAL')
} else {
    print = ('INTERNACIONAL')
  }
```

Minha limitação é de como criar a variável `base$trs_localidade` utilizando a lógica acima.

Comment: Não é possível criar variáveis assim. Você deve criar a variável `base$trs_localidade`, atribuir valor à ela em função do pais e seguir um fluxo ou outro com base em seu conteúdo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para criar variáveis sugiro o uso do pacote dplyr com emprego da função `mutate`. Segue exemplos.

```
library(dplyr)
base <- data.frame(x = c(rep("076", 4), "840", "442",rep("076", 4)))
base
```

```
> base
     x
1  076
2  076
3  076
4  076
5  840
6  442
7  076
8  076
9  076
10 076
```

- Você pode continuar utilizando o `ifelse`, porém prefiro a estrutura aqui demonstrada.

```
base1 <- base %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(iso_pais = ifelse(x == "076", "NACIONAL", "INTERNACIONAL"))
base1
```

```
> base1
     x      iso_pais
1  076      NACIONAL
2  076      NACIONAL
3  076      NACIONAL
4  076      NACIONAL
5  840 INTERNACIONAL
6  442 INTERNACIONAL
7  076      NACIONAL
8  076      NACIONAL
9  076      NACIONAL
10 076      NACIONAL
```

- Ou pode utilizar `case_when` do pacote dplyr.

```
base2 <- base %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(iso_pais = dplyr::case_when(x == "076" ~ "NACIONAL",
                                            x != "076" ~ "INTERNACIONAL"))
base2
```

```
> base2
     x      iso_pais
1  076      NACIONAL
2  076      NACIONAL
3  076      NACIONAL
4  076      NACIONAL
5  840 INTERNACIONAL
6  442 INTERNACIONAL
7  076      NACIONAL
8  076      NACIONAL
9  076      NACIONAL
10 076      NACIONAL
```

E a depender de seu problema, existem outras n soluções, como esta: [Como criar uma coluna no R sob condições específicas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255503/como-criar-uma-coluna-no-r-sob-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-espec%C3%ADficas)

Answer (score 3):

Com a base da [resposta do bbiasi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/385213/r-cria%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-uma-nova-vari%c3%a1vel-usando-if-e-else/385238#385238) com `x` mudado para `iso_pais` tal como vem na pergunta, e usando só R base pode-se fazer destes dois seguintes modos.

O primeiro é de fato o primeiro `ifelse` do @bbiasi, mas sem o `dplyr::mutate`. O segundo modo é um truque de indexação que pode ter vantagens de desempenho se a base for muito grande mas é menos legível que o primeiro.

```
base <- data.frame(iso_pais = c(rep("076", 4), "840", "442",rep("076", 4)))

base$trs_localidade <- ifelse(base$iso_pais == '076', 'NACIONAL', 'INTERNACIONAL')
base$trs_localidade2 <- c('INTERNACIONAL', 'NACIONAL')[(base$iso_pais == '076') + 1L]
base
#   iso_pais trs_localidade trs_localidade2
#1       076       NACIONAL        NACIONAL
#2       076       NACIONAL        NACIONAL
#3       076       NACIONAL        NACIONAL
#4       076       NACIONAL        NACIONAL
#5       840  INTERNACIONAL   INTERNACIONAL
#6       442  INTERNACIONAL   INTERNACIONAL
#7       076       NACIONAL        NACIONAL
#8       076       NACIONAL        NACIONAL
#9       076       NACIONAL        NACIONAL
#10      076       NACIONAL        NACIONAL
```

Answer (score 3):

Ainda mais uma alternativa. Crie a nova variável preenchida com 'INTERNACIONAL' e depois altere apenas as linhas que deseja usando indexação básica:

```
base <- data.frame(
  iso_pais = c( '076', '840', '076','442' , '052' , '076')
)

base$trs_localidade <- 'INTERNACIONAL'
base$trs_localidade[base$iso_pais == '076'] <- 'NACIONAL'

> base
  iso_pais trs_localidade
1      076       NACIONAL
2      840  INTERNACIONAL
3      076       NACIONAL
4      442  INTERNACIONAL
5      052  INTERNACIONAL
6      076       NACIONAL
```

Potencialmente mais rápido em bases grandes do que usar ifelse.

Comment: Usei o script acima, funcionou! Obrigada, bem prático!